# Control single-phase AC motor forward and reverse with relay

Tags: motor, relay, wiring

I have a single-phase AC motor that I want to control with a forward/reverse motor direction [controller I bought from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B098ST3F1P).

The motor I have bought in Peru so I don’t have a link, however the wiring is as follows:

[image]

Can this set-up work? How can I make it work? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is presumed that the reversible AC motor is of the split-phase, capacitor-run type.

It may be controlled by a two-channel, remote wireless relay as shown below.

[image]